# How to implement HTTP Post Create/Update in one method inside Controller? .NET API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api, post, .net-core

I am asking myself how to implement one method inside Controller with HTTP Post to Create/Update entities? Especially what to do if there already exists a entitie with a given primary key and I only want to update some entity properties?

At this moment I am using two Methods, one POST for Create and one PUT for Update.

simplified ControllerCode(left out error handling and model validation):

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Dto[] dtos) 
    {
      foreach(DTO d in dtos){
          _repo.Create(d);
      }
      _repo.Save();
      return StatusCode(201);
    }

[HttpPut]
    public IActionResult Update([FromBody] Dto[] dtos)
    {
      foreach(d in dtos) {
        _repo.Update(d);
      }
      _repo.Save();
      return StatusCode(201);
    }
```

I can't find specific topics for this issue. 
What I don't want to do is read first approach, so that you always have to check in Context, whether there already exists a given entity(same primary key) for updating properties. 
See this microsoft link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-2.0#update-the-edit-page

In Entity Framework 5 there was a method called AddOrUpdate, but it isn't available in EF Core anymore.

Do you have some ideas or useful links how to implement?

Many Thanks! :)

Comment: Create one function and in it's body check if your UniqueID exists, call update method otherwise call insert one.

Comment: You better read [Entity Framework: AddOrUpdate is a Destructive Operation](https://www.michaelgmccarthy.com/2016/08/24/entity-framework-addorupdate-is-a-destructive-operation/)

Comment: you can send one extra parameter from client that act as flag to your web api method and then if `flag="Add"` then you add new entity and if `flag="Edit"` then you just update your entity

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado this post is very useful! Thanks

Comment: @ershoaib you mean an additional entity property or is there a special way to set a parameter  in HTTP Post?

Comment: yes you can add one extra property `Flag` with [NotMapped] attribute means it doesn't concern with database.

Comment: Or you can just check is there entity exist in db with creating one function like `GetById()` so it returns entity if exist then you just check in your method if entity == null then Create or if entity != null then update

Comment: I guess this is the simplest solution to check first wether an entity already exists or not also this can result in multiple db read operations

Comment: is you have any solution or can i give u with example?

Comment: I am implementing my own AddOrUpdate() function and will post a working example here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions idea comes from:
https://www.michaelgmccarthy.com/2016/08/24/entity-framework-addorupdate-is-a-destructive-operation/

This solution is an example with using RepositoryPattern and Generics:

RepositoryBase:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected RepositoryContext RepositoryContext { get; set; }

    public RepositoryBase(RepositoryContext repositoryContext)
    {
        this.RepositoryContext = repositoryContext;
    } 

    // Implements CreateOrUpdate in one function watching the State of an entity
    public void AddOrUpdate(T entity)
    {
        var entry = this.RepositoryContext.Entry(entity);

        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Detached:
                this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
                break;
            case EntityState.Modified:
                this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);
                break;
            case EntityState.Added:
                this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
                break;
            case EntityState.Unchanged:
                //item already in db no need to do anything  
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly RepositoryContext _repo;

    public SomeController(SomeRepository someRepo)
    {
        _repo = someRepo;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateOrUpdate([FromBody] SomeType type)
    {
        try
        {
            // using CreateOrUpdate method makes it necessary to check for existance
            SomeType checkIfExists = _repo.GetById(type.id);

            if(checkIfExists != null)
            {
                // Do some stuff with object
                // ...
                _repo.CreateOrupdate(checkIfExists);
            }
            else 
            {
                checkIfExists = new SomeType();
                // Do some stuff
                _repo.CreateOrupdate(checkIfExists);
            }

            _repo.SaveChanges();
            return StatusCode(201);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error");
        }
    }
}
```